# Toggle append / remove video with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wondered if anyone can help me out - I'm attempting to load a video into the page using jQuery on clicking a button with the class 'toggle'. And on a second click I would like the video to be removed - effectively toggling between append and remove.

Here's the code so far - as it stands the toggle button just continues to add more instances of the video. I realise there's no toggle function in there so far, and hoped someone could shed some light on the best way of achieving this. I'm still learning jQuery :)

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = '<video id="my_video"><source src="animation.mp4" type="video/mp4"/></video>';
    $('#videowrapper').append(content);
    _V_('my_video', {'controls': true});
    });
});
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#my_video').length) {
        $('#my_video').remove();
    }
    else {
        var content = '<video id="my_video"><source src="animation.mp4" type="video/mp4"/></video>';
        $('#videowrapper').append(content);
        _V_('my_video', {'controls': true});
    }
});
```

Comment: well it's hard to think something different from this. +1 too :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($("#my_video").length) {
            $("#my_video").remove();
        }else{
            var content = '<video id="my_video"><source src="animation.mp4" type="video/mp4"/></video>';
            $('#videowrapper').append(content);
            _V_('my_video', {'controls': true});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @RT - actually, F.Calderan posted one second before me, and was the first with the same answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add a check if there's already a video playing, if yes remove it.

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = '<video id="my_video"><source src="animation.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>    </video>',
        search = $('video#my_video').length;
    if(search > 0) {
        $('video#my_video').remove();
    } else {
        $('#videowrapper').append(content);
        _V_('my_video', {'controls': true});
    }
    });
});
```

Something like this should suffice.

Thanks for downvoting me, I accidentally pressed tab to make spaces, which took my focus to the post-button, and then I pressed enter cause i wanted a new line, and it posted my post before I was done :P

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#videowrapper').html(content);
```